# Raise OnPropertyChanged in an async method

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, inotifypropertychanged

In my WPF application I have a method in my view model that

- should run asynchronously
- change the content of the button from "Connect" to "Cancel" to "Cancelling" depending on whether cancel has been pressed or not.

The cancelling itself is working but the content of the button is not updated.
This is an excerpt of my code:

```
public async void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if (cts == null)
    {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        await ConnectDevice(self.CurrentScannedDevice, cts.Token);
        cts = null;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
    }
    else
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
    }
 }
private CancellationTokenSource cts;

public string Name { get // bound to the content of the button
    {
        return cts == null
            ? "Connect Device"
            : cts.IsCancellationRequested
                ? "Cancelling Connecting To Device"
                : "Cancel Connecting To Device";
    }
}
private async Task ConnectDevice(object currentScannedDevice, CancellationToken ct)
{
  //...
}
```

XAML

```
<Button
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Command="{Binding Path=ScanCommand}"
    Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

Comment: where is the XAML binding of Name to the button ? also you are making the cts null just after the await.

Comment: You need to call `OnPropertyChanged` from the method that sets the `cts` to cancelled. Right now your code says that `if (cts == null)` then `cts.Cancel` which would be an NRE anyway.

Comment: @AbinMathew Added the XAML. Cancelling works, so this should not be the problem?

Comment: @JSteward I do. Have a look at the code above. Right after the `cts.Cancel()`. The same button starts the Task can also cancel it.

Comment: @Onur Ah fair enough, I miss read that. Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the getter just before cancelling? I'd be curious to know how many times after cancel that breakpoint is getting hit, if at all.

Comment: @JSteward I found the bug. It was not in the code above, but in the property for the ICommand... See answer below.

Comment: @Onur I dont know how do you fix it but. what i was saying is `await` waits on the `Task` only, not the code written after that. so when you call `await` on the task and right after the code you cancel the cts. that makes the task to be canceled at that point as you are cancelling an ongoing task which is awaited. sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.

In the "real" code, the `Execute` method lives in the command class `ScanCommandImpl`. The property for this ICommand class looked like this:

```
 public ICommand ScanCommand => new ScanCommandImpl();
```

It somehow recreated the ScanCommandImpl, so the variables for cts changed along the way.

Initializing it from the constructor fixed the problem.